# Unix shell script - reads a file with date expirations and notifies when x amount of days are reached -

Tags: shell, datetime

I was wondering if someone can help me with an issue in this date expiry script to only notify 1 time when it reaches the 14 day mark. Currently it will keep counting down to 13,12 days if I don't manually change the date in the file. I've tried changing $seconds_till_expiry -eq $days_14 - but nothing ever happens.

```
#!/bin/sh

> /pathtofile.txt

days_14=$(( 60 * 60 * 24 * 14 ))
days_5=$(( 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 ))
days_1=$(( 60 * 60 * 24 ))
now_seconds=`date "+%s"`

MAIL=/pathtofile.txt

while read expiry id notifications
do

        expiry_seconds=$(date -d $expiry +%s)
        seconds_till_expiry=$(( expiry_seconds - now_seconds ))
        days_till_expiry=$(( seconds_till_expiry / days_1 + 1))
                if [[ $seconds_till_expiry -lt 0 ]]; then
                echo -e "You've been warned. It's Too late :( [$id] password expired on $expiry \n" >> "$MAIL"
                elif [[ $seconds_till_expiry -le $days_14 ]]; then
                echo -e "Warning [$id] passwords expires in $days_till_expiry days on $expiry - contact $email \n "  >> "$MAIL"
        fi

done < /expiryFile.txt

        if [ -s ${MAIL} ]; then

        echo ""| mail -s "Password Expirations"  -- somebogusemail@yadayada.com < "$MAIL"

        else

        exit 0

fi
```

#### expiryFile.txt contents

2021-01-26      test            some notification goes here

Thanks again for your help.

~A

Comment: Do `expiry` and `expiry_seconds` have correct values?

Comment: Hi - The script works fine, except for the fact I can not figure away to make it trigger one time only at the 14 day expiration and then stop after. Ie, the next day it should not report 13 day expiration.

Comment: Maybe you can keep a controfile, which says that it has triggered, and when?

Comment: Thanks - user1934428 - I will keep that in mind and keep looking for a solution. :)